# How to use c# asp.net regular expression to collect multiple anchors' href in a webpage?

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a html page which contains some anchors, I want to collect them into an array.
In those anchors, there are some unwanted anchor like . I don't only choose all anchors, but some of them.
The html of anchor looks like this:

```
<a xmlns="" href="exp3dbasics-c-ExpDesktop-ActionBar.htm#exp3dbasics-c-ExpDesktop-ActionBar">Action Bar</a>
```

The c# code should be:

```
protected string[] GetHref(string html)
{
        Regex regex = new Regex("<anchor>([^<]+)</anchor>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

        Match match = regex.Match(html);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            ............
        }

        return ...;
}
```

Comment: I think you must use HtmlAgilityPack or any other C# HTML parser. All other answers will get downvoted (know from experience). Have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32371771/3832970) and just amend it a bit (remove `&& attribute.Value.Contains(href_text)`) to get what you want. Or here is [another similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30461038/3832970).

Comment: @stribizhev thank you, I like your answer, I'll have a try.

Comment: var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");